# How to access variable in html code using SendGrid?

Tags: php, html, sendgrid

I'm having big issues accessing a variable in my html code.

I have a simple function

```
module.exports =
{
sendEmail(from,to,subject,html)
{
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
transport.sendMail({from,subject,to,html}, (err,info) => {
if (err) reject(err);
resolve(info);
});
});
}
}
```

This works like a charm.

Then in my users.js I have

```
const thissecretToken = randomstring.generate();

const html = 'Hey!!, </br>, Thank you for registering </br> Tu token es: <b> 
${thissecretToken} </b>' ;
```

When i recieve the email, it says literally "${thissecretToken}" And not the token variable.

What am i doing wrong?

Is handlebars changing anything?

EDIT : Solved. I was using ' instead of `

Answer (score 1):

To include variables in a string you need to use different apostrophes. Like this:

```js
const thisSecretToken = "4-8-15-16-23-42"

const html = `Thanks for registering.<br/>Tu token es <b>${thisSecretToken}</b>`;

console.log(html);
document.write(html);
```

Notably that uses `` ` `` and not `'`.